# Vuetify v-autocomplete is not displayed at all, is not rendered, nothing is displayed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have this code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-autocomplete
        label="Autocomplete"
        :items="['California', 'Colorado', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Texas', 'Wyoming']"
    ></v-autocomplete>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "TestPage"
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Nothing is displayed on that page (only `Home` and `Footer`. When I view its HTML, I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

The vuetify is in my dependencies, in `package.json`:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.12.3",
    ...
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information like how you config Vuetify in your App?

Comment: Sound like the component isn't registered. Do you see some warning in the console?

Comment: [@nuxtjs/vuetify documentation](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module) makes it clear right at the top that it's a module for **vuetify 2**.  for vuetify 3 try [this guide](https://codybontecou.com/how-to-use-vuetify-with-nuxt-3.html)